# 0 Results Effecting Entire Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering if there is a way to make a results from a JOIN of a subquery result a predefined entry.

The query below pulls in the `MAX(ReceiveDate)` for the uniqueID `JobNo`. However, if nothing has been received the entire result will not show up. There are several other joins that could have data.

```
--***SUB QUERY (Receiver)
    JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                MAX(cast(r.ReceiveDate as DATE)) as ReceiveDate,
                por.JobNo
            FROM
                POReleases as por
            INNER JOIN
                Receiver as r on por.PONum = r.PONum
            GROUP BY por.JobNo

        ) r
        ON r.JobNo = o.JobNo
```

The query will ultimately pull in data from purchase orders, result the most recent date, and the receiver with its most recent date based on the `JobNo`.

> If nothing is received then result 'Whatever' or NULL. Anything.

**The entire query is below:**

```
DECLARE @now DATETIME
DECLARE @90daysago DATETIME

SET @now = GETDATE()
SET @90daysago = DATEADD(day, -90, @now)


;with cte as

(
SELECT
    o.PartNo,
    o.JobNo,
    ord.DateEnt as oDateEnt,
    por.MAXPONum,
    po.DateEnt as poDateEnt,
    tt.MAXtt,
    r.ReceiveDate,

            CASE
            WHEN po.DateEnt >= r.ReceiveDate AND po.DateEnt >= tt.MAXtt THEN cast(po.DateEnt as DATE)
            WHEN r.ReceiveDate >= po.DateEnt AND r.ReceiveDate >= tt.MAXtt THEN cast(r.ReceiveDate as DATE)
            WHEN tt.MAXtt >= po.DateEnt AND tt.MAXtt >= r.ReceiveDate THEN cast(tt.MAXtt as DATE)
            ELSE po.DateEnt
            END AS MostRecentDate,

    POProrate.TotalCost,
    WIPProrate.WIPProrateCost,
    (POProrate.TotalCost+WIPProrate.WIPProrateCost) as ProratedCost,
    (ROUND(cast((o.QtyToMake - o.QtyShipped2Stock) as FLOAT)/o.QtyToMake,3))*(POProrate.TotalCost+WIPProrate.WIPProrateCost) as TotalProratedCost,

    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY o.JobNo ORDER BY tt.MAXtt DESC) as RowNum

FROM
--***MAIN QUERY (OrderDet)***
    OrderDet as o

--***SUB QUERY (Order)***
    JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                cast(DateEnt as DATE) as DateEnt,
                OrderNo
            FROM
                Orders
        ) ord
        ON ord.OrderNo = o.OrderNo


--***SUB QUERY (POReleases)***
    JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                MAX(PONum) as MAXPONum,
                JobNo
            FROM
                POReleases
            GROUP BY
                JobNo
        ) por
        ON por.JobNo = o.JobNo

--***SUB QUERY (PO)***
    JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                PONum,
                cast(DateEnt as DATE) as DateEnt
            FROM
                PO
        ) po
        ON po.PONum = por.MAXPONum

--***SUB QUERY (TimeTicketDet)
    JOIN
        (
            SELECT MAX(CAST(TicketDate as DATE)) as MaxTT,
                   JobNo
            FROM TimeTicketDet as tt
            GROUP BY JobNo
        ) tt
        ON tt.JobNo = o.JobNo

--***SUB QUERY (Receiver)
    JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                MAX(cast(r.ReceiveDate as DATE)) as ReceiveDate,
                por.JobNo
            FROM
                POReleases as por
            INNER JOIN
                Receiver as r on por.PONum = r.PONum
            GROUP BY por.JobNo

        ) r
        ON r.JobNo = o.JobNo

--***SUB QUERY (POProrate)***
    JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                j.JobNo,
                SUM(j.TotalCost) as TotalCost

            FROM
                (   
                    SELECT
                            por.JobNo,
                    CASE
                        WHEN pod.Unit = 'LOT' THEN SUM(pod.UnitCost*1)
                        ELSE SUM(por.Qty*pod.UnitCost)
                    END as TotalCost
                    FROM
                        PODet as pod
                    INNER JOIN
                        POReleases as por ON pod.PONum = por.PONum and pod.partno=por.partno
                    GROUP BY por.JobNo, pod.Unit

                ) j

            GROUP BY j.JobNo
        ) POProrate
        ON o.JobNo = POProrate.JobNo

--***SUB QUERY (WIPProrate)***
    JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                j.JobNo,
                SUM(j.ProratedCost) as WIPProrateCost

            FROM
                (
                    SELECT
                        tt.StepNo,
                        tt.JobNo,
                        tt.ActualPayRate,
                        tt.BurdenRate,
                        tt.CycleTime,
                        tt.SetupTime,
                        tt.CycleTime + tt.SetupTime as TotalTime,
                        (tt.CycleTime + tt.SetupTime) * tt.ActualPayRate as LaborCost,
                        (tt.CycleTime + tt.SetupTime) * tt.BurdenRate as BurdenCost,
                        ((tt.CycleTime + tt.SetupTime) * tt.ActualPayRate) + ((tt.CycleTime + tt.SetupTime) * tt.BurdenRate) as ProratedCost
                    FROM
                        TimeTicketDet as tt
                ) j

            GROUP BY j.JobNo
        ) WIPProrate
        ON WIPProrate.JobNo = o.JobNo

WHERE
    o.Status = 'Open'
    AND o.JobNo <> ''
    AND ord.DateEnt <= @90daysago
    AND po.DateEnt <= @90daysago
    AND tt.MAXtt <= @90daysago
    AND r.ReceiveDate <= @90daysago



)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE 
RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sub query needs to be a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a regular `JOIN` which will allow it to include results if present and NULL otherwise.

```
--***SUB QUERY (Receiver)
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                MAX(cast(r.ReceiveDate as DATE)) as ReceiveDate,
                por.JobNo
            FROM
                POReleases as por
            INNER JOIN
                Receiver as r on por.PONum = r.PONum
            GROUP BY por.JobNo

        ) r
        ON r.JobNo = o.JobNo
```

Comment: Thank you, I am able to have it read NULL now. I am assuming I can LEFT JOIN each subquery to have it result the same thing for each subquery missing information?

Comment: Yes any subquery/table where there is the possibility for no matching data to exist then a `LEFT JOIN` prevents the other records from being affected by the absence of a match in the subquery/table.

Comment: Welp, that solved every one of the problems I was having. I really appreciate it!